# Using git clean filters for image compression

Tags: git, version-control

Recently when I read about git `clean/smudge` filters, I thought it would be a great way of automatically compressing the images that I add & commit to my repo before I push.

The problem is, I can only have the clean filter, and not a reversed smudge filter to uncompress the image to its original state.

But even if I could, this would be to defeat the point of pre-compressing images in the first place.

This is my `.gitconfig`:

```
[filter "compress-jpg"]
    clean = gm convert -compress JPEG - -
[filter "compress-png"]
    clean = gm convert - -
```

This is my `.gitattributes`:

```
*.jpeg filter=compress-jpg
*.jpg filter=compress-jpg
*.png filter=compress-png
```

To my surprise, I later discovered that git thinks all of the files have been modified after a checkout.

What's the solution to this kind of problem?
Is git clean and smudge only to be used for things that are perfectly reversible?

Is there any way to make git compress and replace my files in the working tree before storing it into the index?

That way, git won't the files get modified after a checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass file name to the script.

Since you dont pass file name it processing all your files.

for example:

```
 git config --global filter.<name>.clean script_file %file_name
```

---

In your case you probably wish to set the file extension ins the `.gitattributes` for the `smudge/clean`.

[***`Read here`***](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) how to config and set it up to support your desired file types.

Comment: I've already setup the `.gitattributes`. But are you saying that simply by changing the clean command to use the `%file_name` it will work? And how does it work? How does it address the "git thinking its a different file"?

Comment: Also I thought these commands are meant to be pipes. Hence the usage of `- -` in my clean command. It's necessary to make `gm` into a pipe.

Comment: If you wish to process all your images files set them in the .gitattributes `*.jpg filter_name` or `*.jpg filter=filter_name`